# ChildEventListener is causing weird behavior

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've simple scenario, where I've to show *green* icon if the current user has commented on post else show *dark* icon the logic is

```
mCommentChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                try{
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.hasChildren() && !dataSnapshot.equals(null)){
                        Comment comment =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                        if (comment.getPostId().equals(mPostId)){
                            mCommentList.add(comment);
                            mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            if (!comment.getUid().equals(Utils.getCurrentUser())){
                                commentImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_comment_dark));
                            } else {
                                commentImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_comment_green));                                
                            }

                            commentTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCommentList.size()));
                        }

                    } else {
                        ///
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //omitting other @overide methods
        };
```

using this code when let say user **USER_1** comments on the Post the icon of commentImageView becomes green on the device of **USER_1**, that's awesome it works, but when the other user **USER_2** comments on the Post the icon of commentImageView becomes green the device of **USER_2**, but icon of the commentImageView becomes dark on the device of **USER_1**

[image]

that is the issue I'm facing as you can see, I want to show green icon on commentImageView for every user, not the for the single user which commented last on the post, where should I make changes so that this ChildEventListener work correctly, any further details will be given on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only set the dark color once when initializing the view when the user logs in (when ever will you need to go from green to dark anyway?). Then your coloring logic simplifies to:

```
if (comment.getUid().equals(Utils.getCurrentUser())){
    commentImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_comment_green));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Man, I spent hours on debugging this issue, but made it simple, Thanks a lot

Comment: @ArshadAli Sure, glad it worked. I've had a lot of problems like this solved here, a fresh set of eye's is all it takes sometimes.